# Build smplayer to LLVM IR and run by lli

Tags: c++, linux, clang, llvm

In ubuntu-14.10_amd64,I compiler smplayer-14.9.0.6690 by clang/llvm-3.4.
I changed the Makefile in src, like:

```
CC=clang 
CXX=clang
CFLAGS = -emit-llvm ...
CXXFLAGS = -emit-llvm ...
LINK = llvm-link
TARGET = smplayer.bc
```

...

At last I got `smplayer.bc`. Then I used

```
$ llvm-dis smplayer.bc -o smplayer.ll 
$ lli -load=... -load=......  smplayer.ll
```

But it got an error:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '__dso_handle' which could not be resolved!
```

Then I used clang to build bc to native executable like this:

```
$ clang smplayer.bc -v -o smplayer.na -m64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lz -lQtDBus -lQtScript -lQtXml -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lQtCore -lpthread
```

The error is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/smplayer-7c5fc5.o: undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_pure_virtual@@CXXABI_1.3'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using '-fno-use-cxa-atexit' with clang.  That should get rid of the use of '__dso_handle'.

http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2013-January/058748.html

It is useful.